# Adding eventSource to Lambda by ARN in CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have a lambda function which reads from Dynamodb stream. I have the Dynamodb stream ARN exported from another stack in the same AWS account. Now, while adding eventSource in Lambda, it asks from Table construct.

```
const function = new lambda.Function(...);
function.addEventSource(new DynamoEventSource(table, {
  startingPosition: lambda.StartingPosition.TrimHorizon
}));
```

Ref: https://awslabs.github.io/aws-cdk/refs/_aws-cdk_aws-lambda-event-sources.html#dynamodb-streams

But I have the stream ARN. Is there any way I can make use of this to add the event source. Or I have to export the table itself?

Comment: Interestingly, other SDKs such as Python have a [`create_event_source_mapping()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.create_event_source_mapping) API call that do, indeed, accept an ARN. That doesn't seem to be present in the CDK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>It's currently not possible to import a DynamoDB table with the AWS CDK.</strike> [Importing a DynamoDB table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-dynamodb.Table.html#static-fromwbrtablewbrattributesscope-id-attrs).

Still you can reach your goal by using the `EventSourceMapping` class from `@aws-cdk/aws-lambda` directly:

```ts
import iam = require('@aws-cdk/aws-iam');
import lambda = require('@aws-cdk/aws-lambda');

const fn = new lambda.Function(...);

new lambda.EventSourceMapping(this, 'DynamoDBEventSource', {
  target: fn,
  batchSize: ...,
  eventSourceArn: <your stream arn>,
  startingPosition: lambda.StartingPosition.TrimHorizon
});

fn.addToRolePolicy(
  new iam.PolicyStatement()
    .addActions('dynamodb:DescribeStream', 'dynamodb:GetRecords', 'dynamodb:GetShardIterator', 'dynamodb:ListStreams')
    .addResource('<your stream arn>/*');
);
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. I have been trying to find this answer for so much time.

Comment: Where does one find the stream arn?

Comment: @Matthew in the DynamoDB console in the "Exports and streams" tab

Answer (score 0):

As the Stream ARN could change every time it's disabled/enabled, one can look up the ARN dynamically and export it as env variable.

> export STREAM_ARN=$(aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name MyFirstTable |jq -r '.Table.LatestStreamArn')

Then this could be used inside CDK Code

> const table = dynamodb.Table.fromTableAttributes(this, 'id-for-table', {
> tableArn:
> "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:123456789:table/MyFirstTable",
> tableStreamArn:process.env.STREAM_ARN
> });